# insertAfter not working with html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

1. I have a `p` Element and try to wrap it inside a `span`.
2. then insert it after the `p` tag with the id `output`.

I tried it like this, but the `insertAfter` is not doing it's job.

```js
$mytext = $("p#test").html();
$myspan = "<span style='color:red'>"+$mytext+"</span";

$($myspan).insertAfter("p#output");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="test">Test</p>
<p id="output">OUTPUT:</p>
```

I also tried it with `append` this works:

```js
$mytext = $("p#test");
$mytext_html = $mytext.html();

$myspan = "<span style='color:red'>"+$mytext_html+"</span";
$("p#output").append($myspan);
$mytext.remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="test">Test</p>
<p id="output">OUTPUT:</p>
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: Try explaining your intentions in a step by step list, because your run in sentence is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rather use **[.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)** to wrap an HTML structure around element in the set of matched elements.

```
$('p#test').wrap('<span style="color:red"></span>');
```

```js
$('p#test').wrap('<span id="testspan" style="color:red"></span>');
$('#testspan').insertAfter('#output');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="test">Test</p>
<p id="output">OUTPUT:</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the last '>' in your closing tag for the $myspan variable

You have:

```
     $myspan = "<span style='color:red'>"+$mytext+"</span";
```

and it should be

```
     $myspan = "<span style='color:red'>"+$mytext+"</span>";
```

Best

Comment: Ohh... thank you. I wonder why it works at my second example with `append` even though i also forgot the `>`

Comment: Hum, that's a good question. After a bit of research, .append() seems to automatically adding closing tags to your string. You can try for yourself without the entire </span and you will see that .append() actually closes the tag for you